# How to install SSL Certificate into Service Bus 1.1 on Windows Server

Tags: windows-server-2012, ssl-certificate, azure

For test cases and evaluation we installed 2 nodes with "Azure Service Bus 1.1" on Windows Server 2012 R2 machines.

The installation process installs the https endpoints with a self-signed certificate which is not trusted through our domain.

In whitepapers I have red that there are two relevant certificates for Service Bus:
"Encryption Certificate" and "Farm Certificate". How can we change the certificate?

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Set-SBCertificate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj614319(v=azure.10).aspx) command.

Example:

```
Set-SBCertificate `
  -EncryptionCertificateThumbprint ‎<thumbprint> `
  -FarmCertificateThumbprint ‎<thumbprint> `
  -SBFarmDBConnectionString "Server=sqlserver;Trusted_Connection=true;Database=SbManagement;Connect Timeout=300"
```

Also take a look at these blogposts:

- https://roysvork.wordpress.com/2014/06/14/developing-against-service-bus-for-windows-1-1/
- http://www.22bugs.co/post/sb-farm-setup-dns-and-custom-certificate/
- http://www.22bugs.co/post/sb-farm-errors-and-their-solutions/